# Winforms auth using current account password

Tags: c#, winforms, authentication, uac

In my win-fourms application, I would like to do something like to use the account password similarly to how apple has the touch id API. I could not find any information on this. Here is an example I saw in the built in groove music app in windows 10:
[image: Auth image]

Thank you!

Comment: We need a bit more information. Where do you get the credentials from? Server or Local? And what credentials are you using?

Comment: @IanH. Pretty sure he is trying to authenticate against the logged in user's Microsoft account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Microsoft built the Universal Windows Platform (UWP) they built in an authentication library that allows you to use user's Microsoft Accounts. There is no built in support for this in WinForms or WPF apps.

However, you *can* use the Microsoft OAuth endpoint to accomplish the same thing, it just won't look the same (requires a browser popup for starters). More information can be found here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code

The code basically requires doing a bunch of REST calls and providing a listening socket for an asynchronous response.